# Destroying embed objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe, video, embed

I have a video add that automatically shows up on the bottom left corner of the users screen when a page loads.  The user can push a button to destroy the add, unfortunately it doesn't destroy it completely.  The flash options are still available like play.  Which can be problematic if there are functional elements on their page (like buttons) and the ad is blocking the user from using the elements.

Additional Information:
The video add is being using as part of the embed tag, and clients are using a javascript include to include the video add to their page.

I also have it sorta working using an iframe for the flash portion but it's behaviour is not consistent between each browser so I want to move away from putting it in an iframe.

I also don't know flash nor have the flash source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery :

```
$('.ads').remove();
```

It should remove completly this part from the HTML code.
In Pure Javascript, you need to know the parent tag, you certainly don't know. (And the parent will NOT be removed)

```
<div id="ParentDiv">
<div id="YourAd" class="ads">This is another paragraph.</div>
</div>
<script>
var parent = document.getElementById("ParentDiv");
var child = document.getElementById("YourAd");
parent.removeChild(child);
</script>
```

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_elementremove)

Comment: You can use element.parentNode.removeChild(element)

Comment: element.parentNode.removeChild(element) did the trick! thanks both of you :).

Comment: No problem! Hope your ads will NEVER annoy me. Have fun in your life! :D